# Saving settings XML -> Database

Tags: sql, xml, delphi

Today I was asked to write a unit and save it's settings into an XML file (`TXmlDocument`).
Then the XML file is to be stored in a `varchar(MAX)` field in SQL Server.

All this is done from within Delphi 7.

I can see the advantage of not having to add additional fields to the table to store the settings.

However, I though XML was used primarily to facilitate the transport of data. Furthermore do we really need another layer to get to the database if we are running local?

Reading from the database is done in a similar manner - read into a `TXmlDocument` and then process.

Not all units use this approach. It is used mainly for storing/reading 3rd party settings.

Now my question is whether this is standard practice and whether it is advised at all?

Thanks for your valuable input.

Edit:

Some context hopefully.

We communicate with 3rd parties.
Each 3rd party has settings which we use to communicate with them.

Now instead of saving each of these settings in a different field in a SQL table, we generate an XML document from Delphi and populate it with the settings for a certain 3rd party.
Then this XML doc is stored in a single field in the table (as opposed to multiple atomic fields).

Comment: If it's a `TXmlDocument` - why aren't you storing this in SQL Server as `XML` ???

Comment: What are you going to do with the data?

Comment: I do not know that... I was asked to do this task by my senior dev.

Comment: We can hardly judge whether or not this is wise with no context. I suppose part of my problem as well stems from not know what you mean by "write a unit and save it's settings into an XML file". What's a unit here? What are the settings of a unit?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The data is read again by the same application to do some processing. As mentioned, this data is settings like servername, tablename etc.

Comment: So why to db rather than local file? Wouldn't it be easier for you to ask your boss? Essentially the answer to your questions is that you can either 1) Do the task ask your boss instructor, or 2) go back to you boss to ask for clarification.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am currently busy doing the task given to me. The answer I got when I asked why XML->SQL is that we do not have to add additional fields to the table that stores this data. Sorry if my question is unclear - these settings are 3rd party settings so they need to be stored in the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely normal! Instead of many different tables with different columns for different settings, you can use one key-value table with the settings XML in the value.

We do this for a program where info for many different reports is stored in the database. The report component can save its own settings as XML and we store that XML in the database. I am not interested at all in the contents of the XML, it might as well be binary data. When we need to load back the settings kust fetch the XML and assign it to the component.

Let go of the idea that you always need different database table fields for different data.